# How can I configure react-router to with nginx/cherrypy and my current reactjs app

Tags: nginx, reactjs, react-router, cherrypy

I have a working web app served by nginx with cherrypy in the backend and ReactJS for the front-end.

The app grew so I want to use react-router to provide quick access to pages with URLs. 
For example I want that my.domain.name/user will get the part in my app that manages user.

My single index.html includes the js bundle like this: 
`<script src="/js/bundle.js"></script>`

Until now my app started by rendering AppMain.
Now, I created a NoMatch class and I've put both into a react-router, like this:

```js
ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={AppMain}>
            <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('main-central'));
```

When trying this it worked nicely. Using http://my.domain.name gave me the app as before. 
But thoeritcally now trying http://my.domain.name/whatever should have renderred whatever NoMatch is rendering. But instead I get the nginx 404 page.

So I believe an nginx-side configuration is needed but maybe  not only (which is why I brought the entire story above).

Nginx configuration (http part) looks like this:

```
upstream app_servers {
    server 127.0.0.1:9988;
}

# Configuration for Nginx
server {

    location / {
        root /var/www;
        index index.html;
    }

    # Proxy connections to the application servers
    # app_servers
    location /api {
        proxy_pass         http://app_servers/api;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

As you can see cherrypy is getting all /api/* paths.

I have static content under /css, /img etc that I want to be served properly.

So I need everything not static and not /api to go to js/bundle.js

How do I configure that in nginx?
Do I need to do something in cherrypy or javascript differently?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Found my own answer...  Here is is:

Basically nginx configuration needed redirect urls to /index.html (not to my bundle.js, of course)

The addition of **try_files** in nginx conf takes care of that:

```
location / {
    root /var/www;
    index index.html;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Additionally I modified the router's main rednering:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
    (<Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={AppMainNewNav}>
            <Route path="users" component={UsersPage}/>
            <Route path="about" component={About}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
    </Router>)
    , document.getElementById('navbar'));
```

And in AppMainNewNav render() I modified the navigation to something like this:

```js
<nav>
    <ul role="nav">
        <li><Link to="/videos">Videos</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: index index.html and try_files index.html worked for me!

Comment: this neat try_files router trick can be used in a Google Storage Bucket without a nginx webserver :) https://www.ackee.cz/blog/en/how-to-host-static-react-apps-in-google-storage-bucket-behind-cloudflare-cdn/